# code blocks error: no input files. C code

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

I just installed code blocks after I did format to my PC. currently, I work on windows 10 pro 64-bit and every time I open a project and run it I face an error it says as in the image; no input found.
[image]

I program C code on code blocks by GCC compiler.
I tried to search online but it isn't a popular problem and I hadn't found anything works.

I hope you can help guys and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not format questions as links

Comment: Try using a path with only ASCII in it.

Comment: You should look at the first error first.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain what do you mean by " using a path only with ASCII in it", HolyBlackCat?

Comment: Try using a path/location which only uses characters from the rather restricted set as defined by the Arabic Standard Code for Information Interchange. I.e. one or more of the folder names seen in the screenshot are suspected of irritating the build environment. E.g. "C:\Users\ahmet\OneDrive\sata_almaktab\practice-linked-list". Probably incorrectly transcribed, please excuse my restricted skill in that language.

Comment: You have some arabic (?) letters in the name of the directory where your code is. Try using only english letters.

Comment: Thank you, guys. The problem has been solved. as you said, I had named a couple of main directors in Arabic which made confusion for the editor to fetch or access the files.

Comment: Consider creating an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem happened because I named my Desktop directory in Arabic, which the compiler couldn't find the project file that I was working on.

So, in general, be sure of the names of the main directories on your PC that are written in the English language.